# setting inferior-R-args variable in init.el has no effect

Tags: init-file, ess

I am trying to set a variable for ESS.  This is how I load ESS:

```
;; ess / try to not (require 'ess-site) as it slows down start-up
(autoload 'R-mode "ess-site.el" "Major mode for editing R source." t)
(autoload 'Rd-mode "ess-rd" "Major mode for editing R documentation." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[rR]\\'" . R-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[Rr]out" . R-transcript-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rd\\'" . Rd-mode))
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("Rscript" . R-mode))
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("r" . R-mode))
```

I tried

```
(eval-after-load "ess"
  '(progn
     (setq inferior-R-args "--no-save --quiet")))

(eval-after-load "ess-site"
  '(progn
     (setq inferior-R-args "--no-save --quiet")))

(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq inferior-R-args "--no-save --quiet")))

(setq inferior-R-args "--no-save --quiet")

(setq-default inferior-R-args "--no-save --quiet")
```

But none works.  When ESS starts, the value of `inferior-R-args` is `""`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you restart Emacs after making these changes? Sorry, just trying to get the obvious out of the way. Did you actually evaluated the `setq` form? I.e. did you `C-x e` on it? (Alternatively, you could `C-: (setq inferior-R-args "--no-save --quiet")`.

Comment: Yes, I did restart. If I evaluate `inferior-R-args` in the \*scratch* buffer after starting Emacs, I get void variable. If I evaluate the `setq` form in \*scratch* and then start ESS, everything works as expected. But the `setq` in the init file does nothing. Strange... OK mystery solved, I had an init.elc lying around.

Comment: Well, you need to `setq` only after that variable is declared somewhere with `defvar` or similar. So, I'd try to first `(require 'ess)` or `(require 'ess-site)`, (I think the later should load the variable declaration), and then to `setq` it.

Comment: It's not necessary, you can `setq` before `defvar`. I don't know if it's a recent feature but it works.

Comment: Yes, it's not necessary, but it may have a different effect. The code initializing the variable my try to check for previous values. Or, there can be other code that runs assuming the variable hadn't been initialized yet and so on. So, just to make sure, I'd wait for the library to load and only then tried to customize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inferior-r-args` is a customization variable, so you can edit it via `M-x customize-variable inferior-r-args`.

ESS is a fairly complex package, and figuring out the timing for modifying variables can be a bit tricky - easier to use the customize facility when possible!